# Как реализовать проверку суммы значений в инпутах через php?

Tags: php, html, sql

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть 5 инпутов, которые пользователь должен заполнить числами, все поля записываются в бд, затем, чтобы была возможность перейти на следующую страницу, нужно проверить, что суммарно в инпутах значение не более 200, пытался реализовать это на php, но с куском кода ниже php файл выдает ошибку, подскажите, как можно решить эту задачу?

```
if(!is_numeric($q5proclang) || (!is_numeric($q5proclang2))|| (!is_numeric($q5proclang3))|| (!is_numeric($q5proclang4))|| (!is_numeric($q5proclang5)) { 
        $error_result = "Операнды должны быть числами"; 
    }
    else 
      
            $result = $q5proclang + $q5proclang2+$q5proclang3+$q5proclang4+$q5proclang5; 
            
                break;    
        }
}
if(isset($result>200)) {
    echo "Некорректное значение, сумма не должна быть более 200";
 }
```

P.S. Поправил [1][[image: ошибка с поправкой]]

```
<?php


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  
  session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
   $sql = "UPDATE  anketa SET q5lang ='$q5lang', q5proclang ='$q5proclang',q5lang2='$q5lang2',q5proclang2='$q5proclang2',q5lang3='$q5lang4',    q5proclang3 = '$q5proclang5',q5lang4='$q5lang3', q5proclang4='$q5proclang3', q5proclang5 ='$q5proclang4',q6tek='$q6tek',q601='$q601',q602='$q602', q6chmes='$q6chmes',q6chtrimes='$q6chtrimes',q6konec='$q6konec' WHERE id = '$id' ";
  $result = null;
if(
    (!is_numeric($q5proclang))  ||
    (!is_numeric($q5proclang2)) ||
    (!is_numeric($q5proclang3)) ||
    (!is_numeric($q5proclang4)) ||
    (!is_numeric($q5proclang5))
) {
    $error_result = "Операнды должны быть числами";
} else {
    $result = $q5proclang + $q5proclang2 + $q5proclang3 + $q5proclang4 + $q5proclang5;
    // break;
}
if($result > 200) {
    echo "Некорректное значение, сумма не должна быть более 200";
}
    else {
    
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    
catch(PDOException $e)
    
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    

$conn = null;
echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=0;URL=http://co47377.tmweb.ru/354.html>";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это...

тут навел какой-никакой порядок в скобках и вынес объявление переменной `$result` в область видимости проверки

```php
$result = null;
if(
    (!is_numeric($q5proclang))  ||
    (!is_numeric($q5proclang2)) ||
    (!is_numeric($q5proclang3)) ||
    (!is_numeric($q5proclang4)) ||
    (!is_numeric($q5proclang5))
) {
    $error_result = "Операнды должны быть числами";
} else {
    $result = $q5proclang + $q5proclang2 + $q5proclang3 + $q5proclang4 + $q5proclang5;
    // break;
}
if($result > 200) {
    echo "Некорректное значение, сумма не должна быть более 200";
}
```

#### Вариант 2

Можно еще все это дело перенести в массив, пробежаться по нему и сделать проверку для каждого (и там же сложить заодно)

```
$result = null;
$nonNumeric = false;
$error_result = null;

$operands = [
    $q5proclang,
    $q5proclang2,
    $q5proclang3,
    $q5proclang4,
    $q5proclang5
];
foreach ($operands as $operand) {
    if(!is_numeric($operand)) {
        $nonNumeric = true;
        break;
    }
    $result += $operand;
}

if($nonNumeric) {
    echo "Операнды должны быть числами";
} else {
    if($result > 200) {
        echo "Некорректное значение, сумма не должна быть более 200";
    } else {
        echo "Результат: $result";
    }
}
```

После PS

```
<?php
$sql = "UPDATE  anketa SET q5lang ='$q5lang', q5proclang ='$q5proclang',q5lang2='$q5lang2',q5proclang2='$q5proclang2',q5lang3='$q5lang4',    q5proclang3 = '$q5proclang5',q5lang4='$q5lang3', q5proclang4='$q5proclang3', q5proclang5 ='$q5proclang4',q6tek='$q6tek',q601='$q601',q602='$q602', q6chmes='$q6chmes',q6chtrimes='$q6chtrimes',q6konec='$q6konec' WHERE id = '$id' ";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    session_start();
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $result = null;
    if(
        (!is_numeric($q5proclang))  ||
        (!is_numeric($q5proclang2)) ||
        (!is_numeric($q5proclang3)) ||
        (!is_numeric($q5proclang4)) ||
        (!is_numeric($q5proclang5))
    ) {
        $error_result = "Операнды должны быть числами";
    } else {
        $result = $q5proclang + $q5proclang2 + $q5proclang3 + $q5proclang4 + $q5proclang5;
        // break;
    }
    if($result > 200) {
        echo "Некорректное значение, сумма не должна быть более 200";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=0;URL=http://co47377.tmweb.ru/354.html>";
    } else {
        $conn->exec($sql);
        echo "New record created successfully";
        $conn = null;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но вот попробовал оба варианта, оба делают php недоступным, как и в изначальной версии, сейчас отредактирую топик и выложу полный пхп код, возможно, я не так вношу

Comment: @Full0fb3ans напишите как приложите

Comment: Приложил после p.s.

Comment: @Full0fb3ans, поправил там у вас баланс скобок.... но если честно то вопросов стало больше чем ответов... попробуйте самый последний вариант и если что пишите

Comment: Есть продвижение, теперь он хотя бы проходит, но пишет SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory, скриншот приложил

Comment: А, случайно удалил данные со входа, теперь все работает, но появилась другая проблема, он выводит ошибку, только если все поля заполнены, т.е. если одно поле заполнено на >200, то он пропускает вперед

Comment: @Full0fb3ans, а что он должен делать?.. я там закомментировал строку с редиректом. но в той версии скрипта было непонятно куда оно относится. возможно его нужно расскоментировать и поместить в нужную ветку(если вы про это)

Comment: @Full0fb3ans отпишитесь потом

Comment: @Full0fb3ans переставил редирект в кейс с `> 200`. не знаю нужен ли он в другом

Comment: Проблема не в редиректе, возможно, косноязычно выразился, мне нужно, чтобы пхп не пропускал пользователя, у которого суммарно по всем инпутам значение переваливает за 200 и даже если в одном инпуте больше 200, то он не пускает дальше, но это ладно, в любом случае, спасибо большое! Дальше уж сам доделаю, введу проверки просто на каждый инпут дополнительно